# Inconsistent accessibility: property type

Tags: c#

What is wrong with this code ?

```
public ScreenManager _ScreenManager
        {
            get { return screenManager; }
            internal set { screenManager = value; }
        }
        ScreenManager screenManager;
```

and I get this error:

```
Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'ScreenSystem.ScreenManager' is less accessible than field 'ScreenSystem.Screen.ScreenManager'
```

Comment: Worth noting: it's probably not a great idea to start the name of a public property with an underscore.  Underscores are generally reserved for private fields (local variables).

Comment: Can you post some more code? It's kind of hard to get the full picture from what you've posted.

Answer (score 12):

I'm going to assume the type `ScreenManager` is `internal` while the class containing your property is public.

The compiler is saying that a publicly-accessible field (`ScreenSystem.Screen.ScreenManager`) is of a type (`ScreenSystem.ScreenManager`) that isn't publicly-accessible.

Your field should generally be `private` anyway.  And you might be missing a `public` in front of your class `ScreenSystem.ScreenManager` (it defaults to `internal` IIRC).

Answer (score 4):

Here is your scenario:

```
namespace ScreenSystem
{
    internal class ScreenManager
    {
        public string Test { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ScreenSystem
{
    public class Screen
    {
        public ScreenManager Manager
        {
            get; internal set;
        }
    }
}
```

> **Compiler Output**
>  
>   Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'ScreenSystem.ScreenManager' is less accessible than property 'ScreenSystem.Screen.Manager'

Here are the solutions, depending on what you're trying to do:

- Make the `Screen` class internal
- Make the `ScreenManager` class public
- Make the `ScreenManager` class public and the `Screen` class internal
- Make the `Screen.Manager` *property* internal (and remove the internal set accessor)

Either one of the above will compile without errors. It really just depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: What do you mean? Are you agreeing with my answer?

Comment: My guess is that `ScreenSystem.Screen.ScreenManager` is referring to class `ScreenManager` in namespace `ScreenSystem.Screen` and `ScreenSystem.ScreenManager` references the property `ScreenManager` in class `ScreenManager` (fully qualified to `ScreenSystem.Screen.ScreenManager`).  There is only one class, therefore no namespace issue.  It's just confusing because the class has the same name as the property.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you have `ScreenManager` set up as private or protected yet you are are trying to make a property public that relies on `ScreenManager`. You can't do that.

Make `ScreenManager` public or make `_ScreenManager` the same accessibility as `ScreenManager`.