# Cannot impliciltly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BallSeparation.Ball>' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, generics, type-conversion

I have this error on

```
for (Ball ball; ballList)
```

The error message is

```
"Cannot impliciltly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BallSeparation.Ball>' to 'bool'"
```

May I know how do I solve it?

```
public partial class StartGame : Form
{
    public List<Ball> ballList { get; private set; }

    /**int bBA1; //The x axis from the upper left corner
    int bBA2; //The y axis from the upper left corner 
    int spdBBA1; //The change of x
    int spdBBA2; //The change of y
    **/

    public StartGame()
    {
        this.ballList = new List<Ball>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StartGame_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ballList.add(new Ball(5, 10, 1, 1));
        /**
        //Loads the ball on the screen at bottom of the window
        bBA1 = this.ClientSize.Width / 5; //The x axis the ball is loaded at
        bBA2 = this.ClientSize.Height - 10; //The y axis the ball is loaded at
        spdBBA1 = 1; //The speed of the ball of y
        spdBBA2 = 1; //The speed of the ball of x
        **/
    }

    private void StartGame_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //This foreach loop will run through all the balls in ballList
        for (Ball ball; ballList)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, ball.positionX, ball.positionY, 10, 10);
        }
        /**
        //This is the inner paint color of the circle that is 10 by 10
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, bBA1, bBA2, 10, 10);
        //This is the outline paint color of the circle that is 10 by 10
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, bBA1, bBA2, 10, 10);
        **/
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /**
        bBA2 = bBA2 + spdBBA2;
        bBA1 = bBA1 + spdBBA1;

        if (bBA2 < 0)
        {
            spdBBA2 = -spdBBA2; //If y is less than 0 then it changes direction
        }
        else if (bBA1 < -5)
        {
            spdBBA1 = -spdBBA1;
        }
        else if (bBA2 + 10 > this.ClientSize.Height)
        {
            spdBBA2 = -spdBBA2; //If y + 10, the radius of the circle is greater than the form width then we change direction
        }
        else if (bBA1 + 10 > this.ClientSize.Width)
        {
            spdBBA1 = -spdBBA1;
        }

        this.Invalidate();
        **/
    }
```

Comment: in which part of the code you are getting that error?

Comment: Can you narrow it down to the specific line that's giving you trouble ?

Comment: This (and your other questions here) do not happen to be some form of homework / study assignment, right? Ok...

Comment: @Onots i think he is an "Cookbook programmer" and hasn't really a clue what he is doing :) in c#

Comment: It is a project I am working on.

Comment: @WiiMaxx I never heard that term before. Learn something new every day!

Comment: @Onots i don't know if i translated it well because it's a Germany phrase "Kochbuch Programmierer" a person who copie & past code from the web with out enough knowledge what the code is doing in detail.

Comment: @Guang so you write the code on your own?

Comment: I did not write it solely by myself, but with the help from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is not Java. This is kinda Java:

```
for (Ball ball; ballList)
```

Correct C#:

```
foreach ( Ball ball in ballList)
```

I noticed you are writing a game and using a timer. You may want to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605726/how-to-make-timer-keep-runing-while-loop-wait-for-another-time-result/16606866#16606866), for an explanation why conventional timers aren't normally used in games.

**Edited for followup comment:**

Your Form is public. It has a public property of List of Balls. Now your Ball class most likely is not public. That's inconsistent. Your form should not expose unknown types. Either make Ball public or make the methods and properties exposing the Ball type private.

Comment: [Fixed that last part for you.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WBov3.png)

Comment: Thank you. However, now I have another error on public List<Ball> ballList { get; private set; }. It stated inconsistent accessibility. May I know how do I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

The line `for (Ball ball; ballList)` isn't actually a foreach loop. It's a for loop, with ballList as the condition (hence being treated as a bool). What you probably wanted was

```
 foreach (Ball ball in ballList)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, now I have another error on public List<Ball> ballList { get; private set; }. It stated inconsistent accessibility. May I know how do I solve it?

Comment: @Guang: The search feature on this site works rather well. If that fails, you can even use Google. See this question for an answer: [Inconsistent accessibility: property type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10322581) Also, this issue is covered in the MSDN documentation. Don't be helpless.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the following line:

```
for (Ball ball; ballList)
```

The syntax for a `for` loop is:

```
for (some assignment; some condition; some statement(s))
```

To look through `ballList` like you want, a `foreach` loop instead:

```
foreach (Ball ball in ballList)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
for (Ball ball; ballList)
```

to this:

```
foreach (Ball ball in ballList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Ball ball; ballList)
```

should be

```
foreach(Ball ball in ballList)
```

The second part of a `for` statement is the test-condition (to keep running the loop); thus you are trying to pass `ballList` as a `bool` expression.