# Inconsistent accessibility, property type

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I know there are many questions answered on Stack Overflow about this, so I wouldn't be asking this question if these solutions actually worked for me. Here are some of the questions I've looked at:

[Inconsistent accessibility error C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805610/inconsistent-accessibility-error-c-sharp)

[Inconsistent accessibility: property type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322581/inconsistent-accessibility-property-type)

I've specified all of my classes as being public, as per each solution to the above questions, but I'm still getting the same error. Here is my code:

```
namespace TestResourceManager
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        private List<string> m_ViewOptions = null;
        private List<MachineRow> m_ViewChoices = null;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            m_ViewOptions = new List<string>();
            m_ViewOptions.Add("item1");
            m_ViewOptions.Add("item2");
            m_ViewChoices.Add(new MachineRow("machinename1", "builddefinition1", "description1", "envname1", "envtype1"));
            m_ViewChoices.Add(new MachineRow("machinename2", "builddefinition2", "description2", "envname2", "envtype2"));
        }

        public List<string> ViewOptions
        {
            get { return m_ViewOptions; }
        }

        public List<MachineRow> ViewChoices
        {
            get { return m_ViewChoices; }
        }
    }
    public class MachineRow
    {
        private string MachineName, BuildDefinition, Description, EnvName, EnvType;

        public MachineRow(string _MachineName, string _BuildDefinition, string _Description, string _EnvName, string _EnvType)
        {
            this.MachineName = _MachineName;
            this.BuildDefinition = _BuildDefinition;
            this.Description = _Description;
            this.EnvName = _EnvName;
            this.EnvType = _EnvType;
        }
    }
}
```

This error:

```
Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TestResourceManager.ViewModel.MachineRow>' is less accessible than property 'TestResourceManager.ViewModel.ViewChoices'
```

is occuring on this line:

```
public List<MachineRow> ViewChoices
```

Does anyone know why everyone else's solutions aren't working for my case? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: The code compiles without any problem on my machine. Did you try a Rebuild or Clean/Build?

Comment: Seems fine for me +1 for clean/rebuild. Maybe worth right clicking on `MachineRow` and navigating to the definition, on the off chance it sheds some light (in case a conflicting definition is to blame).

Comment: This isn't the full code - the error message is saying there's an inner class named `MachineRow` inside of `ViewModel`

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I did not try that and I feel dumb for not trying that. I will try it when I am back at my computer and report back.

Comment: edit: posting this comment on @ReedCopsey's answer...

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Cleaning and building worked, I never really realized that that could be the issue. Thanks for your help. The upvote button doesn't appear for me, so I can't +1 your comment. But that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code, as pasted, is not the complete code.  Given the error message: `System.Collections.Generic.List<TestResourceManager.**ViewModel**.MachineRow>`, the issue is that there is an extra inner class, `class MachineRow` defined somewhere inside of your `ViewModel` class.

```
public class ViewModel
{
   // Somewhere before the closing brace, you're defining a MachineRow class that is not public, ie:
   class MachineRow {}
```

Comment: `MachineView` is defined directly below `ViewModel` in my code

Comment: @t3hclwn Make sure the closing brace for `ViewModel` is **before** the declaration of `MachineRow`.